# How to remove a certain character index in a string

Tags: java

Say I have an unknown string of 100+ characters and I want to remove the last characters before the 100th character and replace them with `...`,  deleting every character after the 100th. ie:

`I would like to remove the last three characters before the 100th character and replace them with a period and deleting everything after.`

would become:

`I would like to remove the last three characters before the 100th character and replace them with...`.

What is the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Just use `String#subString`.

Comment: What have you tried yet? [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has some useful methods, you should check out.

Answer (score 1):

Let `String original = ...` denote the first text. Then I suspect the following String is what you seek:

```
String result = String.format("%s%s", original.substring(0, Math.min(100, original.length())), original.length() > 100 ? "..." : "")
```

Comment: This might throw an index out of bound exception..

Comment: I have added a modification based on you comment. However, the question clearly states that the String in question has length above 100.